# How to parse "col" value to Const NameCol in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, compilation, constants

I want to use the same value of "**col**" string from the first sub to "**Const NameCol**" in the second sub and tried several ways but couldn't be able to succeed. I am in a hurry any workaround for this problem would be really helpful. The error I got in the last run is "***Compile Error: Const Expression required***" on the second sub. If I write "**const Namecol = "B"** " it will work but it doesn't link with col string.
Here is the code:

```
Sub CopyTest()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsnew As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim col As String

    col = InputBox("Enter column name")
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy of Products-Export-2020-Ap")

    For i = 2 To ws.Range(col & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    CopyConditional ws, ws.Range(col & i).Value
    Next i

End Sub

Sub CopyConditional(wshS As Worksheet, WhichName As String)
    Const Namecol = col
    Const FirstRow = 2

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim SrcRow As Long
    Dim TrgRow As Long
    Dim wshT As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wshT = Worksheets(WhichName)
    If wshT Is Nothing Then
        Set wshT = Worksheets.Add(After:=wshS)
        wshT.Name = WhichName
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    wshT.Rows.Clear
    wshS.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=wshT.Cells(1, 1)

    TrgRow = wshT.Cells(wshT.Rows.Count, Namecol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LastRow = wshS.Cells(wshS.Rows.Count, Namecol).End(xlUp).Row

    For SrcRow = FirstRow To LastRow
        If wshS.Cells(SrcRow, Namecol) = WhichName Then
            wshS.Cells(SrcRow, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wshT.Cells(TrgRow, 1)
            TrgRow = TrgRow + 1
        End If
    Next SrcRow

End Sub
```

Comment: You can either declare the variable at module level, or pass the value by argument to the called Sub.

Comment: But I make col as const it gives an error that constant expression required & when I make Name Col string code doesn't work either.

Comment: You need to declare it as a variable, not as a constant

Comment: It doesn't have to be a `const` for your use to work. Follow @RonRosenfeld advice and create a third parameter for your sub `nameCol As String` and it should work.

Comment: `Sub CopyConditional(wshS As Worksheet, WhichName As String, col As String)`  and use `Dim  Namecol As String` instead of `Const Namecol = col`, `then call the function: `CopyConditional ws, ws.Range(col & i).Value, col`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a [constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-constants) is *constant* and does not change. The right-hand side of a `Const` declaration *cannot* be a variable expression (which `col` is, because the user is inputting it).

```
Const nameCol As String = "B" '<~ this is good
Const nameCol As String = col '<~ col can change ... so by definition, this is bad
```

To fix your issue, you can add an additional parameter to `CopyConditional` and pass in the `col`.

```
Sub CopyConditional(ByVal wshS As Worksheet, ByVal WhichName As String, ByVal Namecol As String)
   ' remove the Const Namecol = col line
```

Then when calling `CopyConditional`:

```
CopyConditional ws, ws.Range(col & i).Value, col
```

Answer (score 2):

@BigBen showed you how to modify your code by passing `col` to the called Sub.

Here is how you might modify your code, having declared `col` as a module level variable:

```
Option Explicit
Public col As String
Sub CopyTest()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsnew As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    'Dim col As String

    col = InputBox("Enter column name")
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy of Products-Export-2020-Ap")

    For i = 2 To ws.Range(col & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    CopyConditional ws, ws.Range(col & i).Value
    Next i

End Sub

Sub CopyConditional(wshS As Worksheet, WhichName As String)
    Dim Namecol As String: Namecol = col
    Const FirstRow = 2

…
```